Angular 18 Multiple instance of same service
I've:
service DataLoader who read/write data in DB.
service Report who instances DataLoader using inject
standalone component who inject DataLoader and Report too.
At this point, only one instance of DataLoader its running, and I need to have inside Report, exclusive instance of DataLoader, my conflict its because when component tries to use some functions, the values inside still from the last usage(Report), and I need to stay values from component instance.
In resuming, I think I need multiple instances of DataLoader and somehow inject inside in others services too

Find solution: I created one module and put inside all services who share one single instance. So in DataLoader, I let @Injectable({ providedIn: 'any' }), and in component, add to providers DataLoader (for individual) and in imporrts, I put this new module.

So there is no way to avoid the module?

I didnt find. Ive tried all the ways.

In your componenet decorator
@Component({
selector: 'my-component',
providers: [MyService], <--- here add your service 
templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
})

Instance of a service is created for each declaration in provider property of a decorator and if provided it will be used over the one crated in root.
If you only want to have exlusive instance and don't want to have one in root in your service decorator:
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root',
})

delete
{
    providedIn: 'root',
}

so only
@Injectable()

remains. Remember if you do that. You will need to add it to providers array of a component or a parent component in order for it to work otherwise you will get NullInjectorError

Thanks for the anwser ;)
But and I need to inject "MyService" inside another service "OtherService". How can I do that? And "MyService" have our injections, like "ToastService, SessionService"

How about doing what I wrote in my answer and add your services to providers in app.module? Then simply using inject(YourService)?

Im not using module, its all standalone. What do you suggest to me? :)
